# How do I Create an AutoCounter Column in a Table in SQL 2008 R2?

Tags: database, sql

There is nothing in the "Data Type" drop-down that indicates an auto-counter.
I selected `int` and I am assuming there is a setting somewhere else to turn it into an auto-counter.
The idea is to have a 100% unique ID for my primary key, and every time a row is added it gets the next available ID number assigned to it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bottom pane look at Column Properties.

Expand Identity Specification and set the following values:
(Is Identity): Yes
Identity Increment: 1
Identity Seed: 1